# How to remove duplicate results in splunk

Tags: duplicates, splunk

Is there any way to remove duplicate values in splunk enterprise?

I have tried using `dedup`, but it gives only what is duplicated.

I want to grab only the results which are unique.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

```
| dedup _raw
```

Do this after your base search. 
This will remove duplicate raw events

Answer (score 0):

If you have permission to delete command you can remove duplicate data by piping (|) a search to the delete command.
This should be the opposite of dedup:

... | eventstats max(_indextime) AS latestIndexTime by source|where_indextime

Or you can just search for latest results. 
 ... | eval _time=(_indextime) | stats latest(*) by source